# MongoDB C# .NET Driver connect with credentials

Tags: c#, mongodb

Есть запущенный сервер *MongoDB*. В нем есть БД с таким user, например:

```
>>db.createUser(
{
user: "user_name",
pwd: "user_passwd",
roles: [{role: "readWrite"}]
})
```

Теперь мне нужно из программы c# сделать коннект и использовать эту БД. Но не могу найти подходящего ответа на вопрос **как** это сделать?

Пробую вот так вот (код совершенно не закончен):

```
connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
MongoUrlBuilder mongoUrlBuilder = new MongoUrlBuilder(_connectionString);            
MongoCredential credentials =
MongoCredential.CreateCredential("test", "user_name", "user_passwd");

MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();            

MongoClient _client = new MongoClient(mongoUrlBuilder.ToMongoUrl());
IMongoDatabase _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
```

Но не могу найти, где использовать эти самые *MongoCredential*. 
В оффициальной документации об этом [написано](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/authentication/), но что дальше делать?

И пользуясь случаем, хочу спросить у знающих, в чем разница между **MongoServer** и **MongoClient** классами в C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать подключение к *MongoDB* с настройками приватности (логин, пароль) можно инициализировав поле *Credentials* в объекте *MongoClientSettings* и создав объект *MongoClient* с такими настройками:

```
try
{
    _clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings
    {
        Credentials = new[]
        {
            MongoCredential.CreateCredential(_databaseName, _login, _password)                        
        },
        Server = _mongoUrl.Server,
    };
    _client = new MongoClient(_clientSettings);                    
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Source + " " + e.Message);
}
```